# C++: alternative way to create nested vectors

Tags: c++, arrays, vector, stl

I need to create a 10-dimensional array, and would like to use stl::vector, but I would have to declare something such as:

```
vector< vector< vector< vector< vector.....< int>>>>...
```

Is there an easier way?

Comment: What do you need 10 dimensional array for?

Comment: [`boost::multi_array`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/multi_array/doc/reference.html)?

Comment: @Xarn testing out string theory equations? :)

Comment: I need it for dynamic programming, there are a lot of state variables,
can't use boost, it's for a online judge exercise.

Comment: @MattMcNabb you would need 11 at least :))

Comment: You probably need to consider another data structure, whatever the application. Maybe a sparse matrix from the Eigen math library. Anyway, this is a duplicate as this exact metaprogram is in the linked answer.

Comment: @MattMcNabb I can imagine many applications involving ten-dimensional vectors in the linear algebra sense (i.e. elements of ℝ^n or the like). However, ten-fold nested C++ `std::vector`s hint at describing the *entirety* of a ten dimensional space, which strikes me as infeasible due to the curse of dimensionality (even if each dimension only has an extent of two, there are 1024 points) and also rather odd: How often does one deal with the whole space, rather than some set of samples from the space?

Comment: @delnan 10 dimensional vectors (as in vectors, not `std::vectors`) are pretty boring and small. 10 nested vectors are madness. :-D

Comment: @Xarn A ten dimensional search space is enough for quite a few interesting optimization problem. But yes, the real fun starts at hundreds and thousands of dimensions, or even a variable (unbounded) number of dimensions.

Comment: You can also use a flattened version (only a `std::vector<double> for example`) and have an accessor that translates from multi-indices to `size_t` and vice-versa. I use such structures frequently and just wrote a wrapper for vector in which I overloaded the `operator[]` to work with multi-indexes, using a syntax like `v[{1,2,1,4}] = 2.5`, where the initializer list specifies the multi-index.

Comment: @vsoftco In fact, `std::valarray` is a standard facility that does just that. But, that requires the matrix to be (hyper-)rectangular, so the size is the product of all the bounds. With 10 dimensions, it's sure to exceed the system's memory.